# why should I use a scalar macro instead of a function with pragma UDF

Tags: oracle

I've read that a scalar macro can speed a query. But I read too that the pragma PRAGMA UDF speed it.

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9e79ed31707e329c5f169f815e546a5b)

```
WITH
 FUNCTION fc 
        RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO(scalar)
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN q'{
      1
  }';
    END;
SELECT fc()
  FROM dual
 
WITH
 FUNCTION fc 
        RETURN integer
    IS PRAGMA UDF;
    BEGIN
        RETURN      1;
    END;
SELECT fc()
  FROM dual
```

both solutions work. Personaly I prefer using UDF because I know which type returns the function.

Why would be a macro better?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/UDF-pragma.html) states: *"The UDF pragma tells the compiler that the PL/SQL unit is a user defined function that is used primarily in SQL statements, which **might** improve its performance."* While `SQL_MACRO` is a SQL code without context swithes (and is embedded into the SQL statement at the cursor compilation time)

Comment: @astenxt Ok. In my example my function  is  defined inside a with block. Therefore no context switch should happen, right?  Is it necessary to macro sql_macro (and udf ) in a with block?